Compatibility of Initial/Boundary Conditions in a Convection-Diffusion Problem?
So, I'm reading a book that numerically solves the following convection-diffusion problem
$$\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t} + c\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \alpha\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} \qquad 0\leq x\leq 1$$
with the initial and boundary conditions
$$u\left(0,t\right) = 0\qquad u\left(x,0\right) = e^{-200\left(x-0.25\right)^2}$$
I am confused, however, if this is even well-posed; specifically, if $u\left(0, t\right) = 0$, then it should be for $t=0$ as well, right? But, then, clearly, the boundary condition does not satisfy this constraint... am I missing something here?

You are correct that this will have an effect. The effect of this will be that $u(x,t)$ will not be continuous exactly at the point $(0,0)$. However, many PDEs are well-defined even for initial/boundary conditions with lower regularity than the number of derivatives in the PDE suggests. Parabolic PDEs such as this one are particularly nice, as solutions for $0<x<1$, $t>0$ tend to have higher regularity than the initial and boundary conditions. These sorts of discontinuities can lead to problematic behavior when, for example, the diffusion is very small and large gradients are advected throughout the domain, sometimes requiring mesh refinement.

could you comment a bit more on what regularity means in this context? I found something similar after posting that claims that if regularity conditions aren't satisfied, we might still get a solution at the expense of uniform convergence. Is this a standard notion in PDE theory (of which I do not know much, admittedly)?

Regularity in this context means that the solution on the interior is typically smoother (more continuous derivatives with stronger integrability properties) than the boundary conditions are. The idea that the notion of convergence when considering $\lim_{t\to 0} u(x,t)$ must be made weaker when the intial/boundary conditions are not compatible is also a pretty general phenomenon. If BC/ICs are not smooth, then this convergence may only be pointwise or weakly convergent instead of uniform.
